# How to play facebook videos in android?

Tags: android, facebook, video-streaming

I tried to play facebook videos in android, but it does not work.

I used this lib:

```
implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'
```

and then I set up the player like this:

```
playerView.setOnPreparedListener(this)
playerView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10201503228394922"))
playerView.start()
```

According to this post this should work:
[Playing facebook video in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627748/playing-facebook-video-in-android)

I tried other things too, but nothing works. Is there a way to play facebook videos in an android app?

Update:
I added a webView and I tried to load a video like this:

```
showsWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=341752630182567")
```

It works sometimes, but it is not reliable, because it just stops sometimes and the webView becomes all black.

Comment: The video URL needs to be a video. It is a HTML document. In the post you link to they use a webview to display the HTML document.

Comment: have you tried to play facebook videos in Android. Do I need to integrate the facebook sdk? and is it possible to display videos without making the user have to log in case I need to use their sdk?

Comment: No I have not any of those things. I'm just telling you what is wrong with your current solution